# Multiple provider network management on different neutron nodes

Tags: openstack, high-availability, provider, openstack-neutron

I want to install neutron server on different Nodes. In my environment there will be 3 provider networks name provider1, provider2 and provider3 with respectively. All of them will be flat network. In my system, I want each neutron server manages different provider networks (neutron1 only controls provider1, neutron2 controls provider2 and neutron3 controls provider3). VMs will have internal networks (overlay network) and use Virtual Routers to access provider networks. The interface mapping on neutron servers are as given below:

**Neutron 1**

```
Bond 0 : Management + overlay
Bond 1 : use for provider1
```

**Neutron 2**

```
Bond 0 : Management + overlay
Bond 1 : use for provider2
```

**Neutron 3**

```
Bond 0 : Management + overlay
Bond 1 : use for provider3
```

Virtual router(VR) is randomly scheduled across multiple OpenStack Networking nodes. My question is how I can deploy VR on specific neutron node (like VR which has GW address from provider1 will deploy on neutron1) ? or I will create high available VR, in this case VR will deploy all neutron servers. How can I select the active virtual router in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I thought the DVR(Distributed Virtual Router) is helpful for your case.

I describe some differences between DVR and non-DVR based on VM access routes.
The DVR is generated Virtual Router at each compute node that has VMs to decrease overloads of Network node and SPOF.

Differences based on how to route.

```
VMs running node          | subnet    | using router at DVR                       | non-DVR
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
all on the same node      | different | Routing from each VM running compute node | Specified Network node (running L3agent node)
all across multiple nodes | different | Routing from each VM running compute node | Specified Network node (running L3agent node)
```

Difference when using Floating IPs. (but accessing from external to internal (SNAT) is not HA, just one node can routing it as of Ocata.)

```
DVR                           | non-DVR
-------------------------------------------------------
each DVR has each Floating IP | Just Network node only
```

As following configuration steps were based just a simple pattern, you need to refer the [official tutorials](https://docs.openstack.org/ocata/networking-guide/deploy-ovs-ha-dvr.html) for adopting your system.

**Prerequisite: all compute nodes have installed l3, dhcp, metadata, openvswitch agents.**

Enable the DVR at all compute nodes.

```
# vim /etc/neutron/neutron.conf

[DEFAULT]
...snip...
router_distributed = True
...snip...
```

Adding the l2population driver at controller node.

```
# /vim/etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/ml2_conf.ini

[ml2]
...snip...
mechanism_drivers = openvswitch,l2population
...snip...
```

Configure the SNAT router on the specified compute node.

```
# vim /etc/neutron/l3_agent.ini

[DEFAULT]
...snip...
agent_mode = dvr_snat
...snip...
```

Configure the agent mode to DVR on the remaining compute nodes.

```
# vim /etc/neutron/l3_agent.ini

[DEFAULT]
...snip...
agent_mode = dvr
...snip..
```

Edit openvswitch config on all compute nodes.

```
# vim /etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/openvswitch_agent.ini

[agent]
...snip...
l2_population = True
enable_distributed_routing = True
...snip...
```

Restart for chages to take effect.

On controller node.

```
# systemctl restart neutron-server
```

On all compute nodes.

```
# systemctl restart neutron-l3-agent neutron-openvswitch-agent
```

I hope this will help you.